# why fatal Error 111 error C1083 in VC++

Tags: visual-c++-2005

I used the following syntax:

## import "../vavole/Acoust-ics.dll"

I am compiling with visual studio 2005C++
But while rebuilding the soultion i am getting the following
Error   111fatal error C1083 ,Cannot open type library file: '../vavole/Acoustics.dll': No such file or directory, I have checked the filename and the path provided ,please help me to get the solution.

Comment: The "current" directory might not be what you expect, meaning that the relative path is wrong. What if you give the full absolute path?

Comment: Yeah you were right full absolute path worked perfect,Thanks man! :)